# Matrix: Hide preview

Tags: matrix

Is it possible to hide the preview shown by default when Matrix blocks are collapsed?

> You can collapse Matrix blocks by clicking the “Collapse” menu option,
>   or by double-clicking on a block’s title bar. When a block is
>   collapsed, its title bar will show a preview of its content, so you
>   can still identify which block it is.

It's useful to just be able to see the content outline made up by block types clear and simple. A lot of the time in my case the preview is irrelevant so it would be great to turn this off across the board by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no out-of-the-box way to do this, but you can make use of a plugin like [Lindsey Diloreto's CPCSS](https://github.com/lindseydiloreto/craft-cpcss) to set `display: none` on the `body.ltr .matrixblock > .titlebar > .preview` class.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, that would do the job. It could be quite nice to have this as an option on the matrix field itself though. In some cases a string preview just isn't applicable.

Comment: Sounds like a great opportunity to post in our [feedback forum](http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com/forums/285221-feature-requests)! Can you go ahead and choose the answer as correct to close out the question?